# read realtime database in sequence

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

How to read data from Firebase real-time  sequentially with Flutter?

This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaI5u.png) of a real-time database

[image]

here is the code.

```
void _activateListeners() async {
    try {
      database
          .child('Temperature')
          .child(widget.sensorID).orderByChild('timestamps')
          .onValue
          
          .listen((event) {
        var snapshotValue = event.snapshot.value;

        if (snapshotValue is Map) {
          snapshotValue.forEach((key, value) {
            temperatureList.add(value.toDouble());
          });
        }
        setState(() {});

        print('temperature $temperatureList');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching temperature data: $e');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `orderByChild('timestamps')`, Firebase looks for a child node `timestamps` under each child node and orders on the value of that. But your screenshot shows no such `timestamps` nodes, so the nodes have no values to order on.

If you want to order on the **value** of each child node, use `orderByValue()` instead:

```
  database
      .child('Temperature')
      .child(widget.sensorID)
      .orderByValue() // 
      .onValue
```

Comment: still, it's in unorder sequence

Comment: I want to read the data in the sequence of the above image.

Comment: The Firebase console shows children in the order of their keys, so that'd be `orderByKey()`. Instead of saying " it's in unorder sequence", can you edit your question to show the order you get - e.g. by printing the values and including that code and its output?